# Is there any way to implement customized (except index/count ) facet values sorting in solr?

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4, solrcloud, solrnet

Suppose we are searching with iphone and in Brand facet we are getting the below facets
 1)Amzer
 2)Apple
 3)Araree
 4)Casemate
 5)DailyObjects

It is based on alphabetic order. But we want to sort the facet values based on 
 some customized score of each brand.
Is there any feature available in solr faceting which will fulfil the above requirement?

If we have the score against each brand facet values then is there any way to perform facet in the solr end ?

Currently, solr is having only  two facet.sort options i.e. index and count.
We want to incorporate other sorting option apart from index and count.
Please suggest.

Comment: How many facet terms can we be talking about for a result set? Can you do it in your own middleware?

Comment: In Solr4 there is no any other custom way to sort it. But from Solr5 you can achieve custom sorting via json.facet. For more information http://yonik.com/json-facet-api/

Comment: Thanks for your reply,

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks for your reply.  We are using facet.limit = 500 ,so at most we can get 500 facet values. In middleware, we can implement by writing a comparator but we are trying to sort the facet values based on some other field. Suppose 50 documents are under one facet value and we are trying to figure out the avg value of the field of these 50 docs. Basically, we are trying sort the facet values based on some other custom field(except count or index). As the field is available if solr doc we are not considering middleware implementation.

Comment: However, remember that a term in a facet is just a term in an index - the faceting code does not fetch the complete document for each occurrence of each term - so I don't think that information will be easily available.

Comment: @MatsLindh Is there any feature in solr to retrieve other attributes associated with each facet value. Suppose for facet value apple we want to get what are the documents associated with it. Currently, we are getting only count and name of the facets.

Comment: You usually query that by issuing the regular query again and applying a filter in a `fq`, such as `fq=facet_field:<facet_value>`. That will retrieve all documents that match the value. Maybe result grouping or collapsing will be more useful for your use case if you need all documents per key.

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh we are not using fq because we are not filtering only one facet value but we want to fetch the document info againt each of the facet value .Suppose we have 10 facets and each facet is containing 50-200 values each . We want to calculate average of of some other field associated with each facet values  :"categories":{
      "buckets":[
        {
          "val":"electronics",
          "count":12,
          "x":231.0,//x is average of some other field e.g. Avg(price)
        },
        {
          "val":"memory",
          "count":3,
          "x":86.0,
        },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're talking about aggregation of a field, you can do this by using the [Facet JSON API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/json-facet-api.html):

The example given does what you're asking about:

```
{
  categories:{
    type : terms      // terms facet creates a bucket for each indexed term in the field
    field : cat,
    sort : "x desc",  // can also use sort:{x:desc}
    facet : {
      x : "avg(price)",     // x = average price for each facet bucket
      y : "max(popularity)" // y = max popularity value in each facet bucket
    }
  }
}
```

This sums up the average price of all the elements in the facet, while also sorting by it - giving you the categories with the highest average price first.

The supported list of functions you can use for aggregation under facets is [available in the reference guide](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/json-facet-api.html#AggregationFunctions):

- sum, sum(sales), summation of numeric values
- avg, avg(popularity), average of numeric values
- min, min(salary), minimum value
- max, max(mul(price,popularity)), maximum value
- unique, unique(author), number of unique values
- hll, hll(author), distributed cardinality estimate via hyper-log-log algorithm
- percentile, percentile(salary,50,75,99,99.9), Percentile estimates via t-digest algorithm. When sorting by this metric, the first percentile listed is used as the sort value.
- sumsq, sumsq(rent), sum of squares of field or function
- variance, wvariance(rent), variance of numeric field or function
- stddev, stddev(rent), standard deviation of field or function

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh this info is very much helpful.